# Is there a way to inspect the files inside a PersistentVolume from GKE by using Google Cloud Console?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-console

Consider a pod, whose one of the containers mount a PVC that points to a persistent volume (using NFS storage class). All of it is running over Google Kubernetes Engine. Is there a way to inspect the content of the persistent volume via Google Cloud Console?

Comment: I asked this question because I wanted to give our QA team a straightforward way to investigate a volume, and asking them to deploy a new container with arbitrary code does not sound great. But I don't think what I wanted was possible (I could deploy some kind of volume explorer, but would not be easy) so I gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what's inside the Persistent Disk via SSH onto its node. As all Persistent Disks are needed to be attached to an instance to have access to them.

Or you can also check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/csi-driver) if you are using Filestore instances as Persistent Volumes.